# R create multiple variables with one condition

Tags: r, dplyr, case

Is there a simpler way to write it,create multiple variables for one condition? like this

```
  if am == 1 then do;
    a="";
    b="";
    c=;
  end;
  else if am == 0 then do;
    ...
  end;
```

The following is the R code I wrote

```
library(dplyr)
dt1 <- mtcars
dt2 <- dt1 %>% 
mutate(a = case_when(am == 1 ~ "a1",
                     am == 0 ~ "a2",
                     am == 2 ~ "a3"),

       b = case_when(am == 1 ~ "a2",
                     am == 0 ~ "a2",
                     am == 2 ~ "a2"),

       c = case_when(am == 1 ~ 0,
                     am == 0 ~ 1,
                     am == 2 ~ 2))
```

Answer (score 3):

```
lookup <- data.frame(
  am = c(1, 0, 2), a = c('a1', 'a2', 'a3'), b = 'a2', c = c(0, 1, 2)
)
left_join(dt1, lookup, 'am')
```

Comment: If the data set has many observations, this is not applicable

Comment: I don't follow why you think that.

Comment: Maybe my example is too simple. In fact, there may be more values such as am = = 1, or the conditions such as am = = 1 & VAR1 = = "AA" may be required. The value of a, b and c can also be equal to a variable VAR1, so it is not very appropriate to create a data set and then merge

Comment: Right, but that is not about the number of observations but the complexity of the conditions. `am = = 1 & VAR1 = = "AA"` can easily be done with a join, by adding both those variables to the lookup table. For more complicated conditions I am not sure there is an elegant solution.

Comment: Thank you very much. I found package R data.table. I'm trying to understand and apply compute columns, which may generate multiple variables under one condition